# For Loop not working as expected, multiplies by 10

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop

I'm new to JavaScript React. Can't grasp my head around why this very simple For-Loop won't work as expected? I obviously expect it to Console.Log the values for amountOfPeople, but when I change amountOfPeople to 2, it for some reason counts up to 20. Same when I change it to 3, 4, 5 etc. It multiplies my 10.

This is my **App.js:**

```
import React from "react"

import Main from "./components/Main"

function App() {
  const [amountOfPeople, setAmountOfPeople] = React.useState(1)

  function handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    if (name === "amountOfPeople") {
      setAmountOfPeople(value)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Main 
        amountOfPeople={amountOfPeople}
        handleChange={handleChange}
       />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Main.js**

```
import React from "react"

import InitialForm from "./InitialForm"

function Main(props) {
    return (
        <InitialForm 
            amountOfPeople={props.amountOfPeople}
            handleChange={props.handleChange}
        />
    )
}

export default Main
```

**InitialForm.js**

```
import React from "react"

function InitialForm(props) {
    for (let index = 1; index < (props.amountOfPeople+1); index++) {
        console.log(index) 
    }
    

    return (
        <form>
            <label>Amount of people:</label>
            <select name="amountOfPeople" value={props.amountOfPeople} onChange={props.handleChange}>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    )
}

export default InitialForm
```

Comment: `"1" + 1 == "11"`, which'll convert to `11` when used in a numeric context. JS's type coercion can be a PITA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` of a dropdown is a string, when you bubble the event back up the `amountOfPeople` becomes a string. So when you do this:

```
for (let index = 1; index < (props.amountOfPeople+1); index++) {
    console.log(index) 
}
```

and lets say you have picked `2` then the code becomes

```
for (let index = 1; index < ("2"+1); index++) {
    console.log(index) 
}
```

`"2" + 1` is "21" but then it gets coerced to a number - the number `21`

Ensure the `value` is always a number by preceeding it with `+`

```
setAmountOfPeople(+value)
```

Live example:

```js
function App() {
  const [amountOfPeople, setAmountOfPeople] = useState(1)

  function handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    if (name === "amountOfPeople") {
      setAmountOfPeople(+value)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Main 
        amountOfPeople={amountOfPeople}
        handleChange={handleChange}
       />
    </div>
  )
}


function Main(props) {
    return (
        <InitialForm 
            amountOfPeople={props.amountOfPeople}
            handleChange={props.handleChange}
        />
    )
}


function InitialForm(props) {
    for (let index = 1; index < (props.amountOfPeople+1); index++) {
        console.log(index) 
    }
    

    return (
        <form>
            <label>Amount of people:</label>
            <select name="amountOfPeople" value={props.amountOfPeople} onChange={props.handleChange}>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  var {
    useReducer,
    useEffect,
    useState,
    useRef,
    useCallback
  } = React
</script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you. I'm not very used to converting Data Types since I've primarily been coding in PHP, where it's not really needed.